# Does bluetooth 5.0 provide stereo audio and mic on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone

I've seen that with older bluetooth protocols it was impossible to get stereo audio and microphone working contemporarily in a bluetooth headset.

The aptX codec was needed to do this.

I'm wondering whether now with a broader band of bluetooth 5.0 this could be achieved.

Thanks